# update the initial screenWidth value without having to refresh the page

Tags: javascript

i have the following javascript code:

```
var screenWidth = {"width": document.documentElement.clientWidth}
d3.select(window).on('resize', resize)
function resize() {
    var clientWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth
    screenWidth["width"] = clientWidth
    return clientWidth
}
```

i am using the D3.js library

every time the screen size changes, the function resize does return the clientWidth, but what will be the correct way to update the initial screenWidth value without having to refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the end of your body:

```
(function() {
   // your page initialization code here
   // the DOM will be available here
    var windowWidth = resize();
})();
```